# Oracle Update Column From Other Column Calculation Result

Tags: java, database, oracle, prepared-statement

I have a table `passenger` with the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE passenger (
  id NUMERIC(12,0) NOT NULL,
  station VARCHAR(3), 
  adult NUMERIC(3,0), 
  child NUMERIC(3,0), 
  infant NUMERIC(3,0),
  crew NUMERIC(3,0) DEFAULT 0,
  paying NUMERIC(4,0), 
  non_paying NUMERIC(4,0),  
  total_passenger NUMERIC(3,0), 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The initial record is as follow.

```
id  | station | adult | child | infant | crew | paying | non_paying | total_passenger
100 | GWN     | 20    | 4     | 1      | 2    | 24     | 3          | 27
```

The value of `paying` field is calculated by summing `adult` and `child` value. And, by summing the `infant` and `crew` I can get the `non_paying` value. Then I can sum the `paying` and `non_paying` fields to get the `total_passenger`.

The question is, when I update `adult`, `child`, `infant`, and `crew` fields with the possibly `NULL` value for each field, can the database recalculate the `paying`, `non_paying`, and `total_passenger` without the need to update them manually?

I've tried the following query with unexpected result.

```
UPDATE passenger
SET adult = NVL(NULL, adult),
    child = NVL(6, child),
    infant = NVL(3, infant),
    crew = NVL(NULL, crew),
    paying = adult + child,
    non_paying = infant + crew,
    total_passenger = paying + non_paying
WHERE id = 100;
```

The `NULL` keywords comes from the prepared statement parameter, which is the possibly null value. How to update the last three fields automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger which does an additional update to the `passenger` table after an `UPDATE` happens:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_passenger
AFTER UPDATE OF passenger
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE passenger
   SET
       paying = NVL(:NEW.adult, 0) + NVL(:NEW.child, 0),
       non_paying = NVL(:NEW.infant, 0) + NVL(:NEW.crew, 0),
       total_passenger = NVL(:NEW.adult, 0) + NVL(:NEW.child, 0) +
                         NVL(:NEW.infant, 0) + NVL(:NEW.crew, 0)
END;
```

To use the trigger, you need only to make your updates to `passenger` as usual.  If you do update the `adult`, `child`, `infant`, or `crew` fields to `NULL` for a given record, then my trigger will treat a `NULL` as `0` in the calcuation for the totals.

Comment: Is it allowed to pass one argument in NVL function?

Comment: @Bogie Thanks for pointing this out.  No, it's not allowed, and doesn't even make any sense ^ ^

Comment: Can I use `NVL(:NEW.field, :OLD.field)`, Which means if the new value is null then use the old value? Does the `trigger` will be re-executed if it updates the same table, which is triggered the same `trigger`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `NVL(:NEW.field, :OLD.field)`, and no, the trigger won't generate another trigger (which would be infinite).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle 11g above then consider of using virtual columns.

```
create table passenger(id numeric(12, 0) not null,
                       station varchar2(3),
                       adult           numeric(3, 0) default 0,
                       child           numeric(3, 0) default 0,
                       infant          numeric(3, 0) default 0,
                       crew            numeric(3, 0) default 0,
                       paying numeric(4, 0) generated always
                       as(adult + child) virtual,
                       non_paying numeric(4, 0) generated always
                       as(infant + crew) virtual,
                       total_passenger NUMERIC(3, 0) generated always
                       as(adult + child + infant + crew) virtual,
                       primary key(id));

insert into passenger
  (id, station, adult, child, infant, crew)
values
  (1, '1', 2, 3, 4, 5);
insert into passenger (id, station, child, crew) values (2, '2', 7, 8);

select * from passenger;

/*
ID  STATION ADULT CHILD INFANT  CREW  PAYING  NON_PAYING  TOTAL_PASSENGER
1   1       2     3     4       5     5       9           14
2   2       0     7     0       8     7       8           15
*/
```

Comment: Nice info about virtual column. Unfortunately the existing application I'm working in is still using 10g. Can I update the virtual column manually?

Comment: AFAIK it's not allowed to change the value of a virtual column.